# How to install Storybook to VueJS 2 TypeScript project?

Tags: vue.js, storybook

I am totally new to Storybook and I try to learn how to use it with VueJS. This first problem comes with installation: I have found two or three ways how to add Storybook to my project:

- `npx -p @storybook/cli sb init`
- `vue add storybook`
- `yarn add --dev @storybook/vue`

What is the difference between those options (concerning my project, not used package manager)?

Answer (score 0):

`npx sb init`

according to the latest documentation - https://storybook.js.org/docs/vue/get-started/install

Comment: Well, yes, but my question is about the difference between those methods.